# Calling Google Apps Marketplace UpgradeableApp API with Python Appengine App

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

Is it possible to call the Google Apps Marketplace UpgradeableApp API from a Python Appengine App? The only examples available seem to be for Java / Ruby.

Our App is written in Python / Appengine so we would like to use this - any example code woul dbe much appreciated.

In Ruby it seems to be simple as:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, { site: "https://www.googleapis.com" }) 
resp = consumer.request(:put, "/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/#{listingId}/#{cwsId}/#{domain}") puts resp.code+"\n" puts resp.body
```

Cheers,
Ian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have now solved this - python code below, although not documented you can use the oauth2 library to provide the oauth authentication part:

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/oldlisting/newlisting/mybeacon.biz'

consumer_key = 'key'
consumer_secret = 'secret'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

client = oauth.Client(consumer)

# Step 1: Get a request token. This is a temporary token that is used for
# having the user authorize an access token and to sign the request to obtain
# said access token.

resp, content = client.request(url, "PUT")
```

Hope this helps you out...

Answer (score 0):

The most difficult part will be the OAuth1.0 flow. The OAuth website lists some libraries available for Python:

http://oauth.net/code/

Once you have the OAuth part done it's just a matter of making the PUT request like you included in your question.